# Retrieve function in Power Builder throwing error

Tags: powerbuilder

I'm using power builder version 9. In PB window while clicking on one button its throwing error "invalid cursor". While debugging found the sql query behind the clicked event. After executing the sql query manually its giving me proper output. But at the retrieve function its giving below error in debug mode

1. Sqldbcode= 999
2. “Select error: SQLSTATE = 2400 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Invalid cursor state”. Any help is highly appreciated. thanks

   ```
   string  szPool, szSQL 

   szPool = Message.StringParm
   dw_select.SetTrans(SQLCA)

   szSQL = "SELECT gl_year=convert(int,NULL), gl_period=convert(int,NULL),     comb=max(convert(decimal(8,2),convert(decimal(8,2),gl_year) + convert(decimal(8,2),gl_period) / 100)), " + &
       "fd_changed_hr_id, fd_changed_date, fd_admin_fee_rate " + &
       "INTO #temp1 FROM fd_pool_af_history WHERE fd_pool = '" + szPool + "' GROUP BY fd_changed_hr_id, fd_changed_date, fd_admin_fee_rate " + &
       "UPDATE #temp1 SET " + &
       "gl_year = convert(int,substring(convert(varchar(25), comb),1,4)), " + &
       "gl_period = convert(int,substring(convert(varchar(25), comb),6,2)) " + &
       "SELECT gl_year, gl_period, 0, fd_changed_hr_id, fd_changed_date, fd_admin_fee_rate " + &
       "FROM #temp1 "
   dw_select.Object.DataWindow.Table.Select = szSQL
   dw_select.Retrieve(szPool)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The datawindow is used to query data based on a select statement and then either modify it (insert, update, delete) or use the results returned by the select.

You have 3 separate queries in your String of SQL which isn't how datawindows work (also why it works when you run it manually but not within the datawindow):

(1) fetch data into a temp table

```
SELECT gl_year=convert(int,NULL), 
       gl_period=convert(int,NULL),     
       comb=max(convert(decimal(8,2), convert(decimal(8,2),gl_year) + convert(decimal(8,2),gl_period) / 100)),
       fd_changed_hr_id, 
       fd_changed_date, 
       fd_admin_fee_rate 
  INTO #temp1 
  FROM fd_pool_af_history 
 WHERE fd_pool = <szPool>
 GROUP BY fd_changed_hr_id, 
          fd_changed_date, 
          fd_admin_fee_rate;
```

(2) update values in temp table

```
UPDATE #temp1 
   SET gl_year = convert(int,substring(convert(varchar(25), comb),1,4)), 
       gl_period = convert(int,substring(convert(varchar(25), comb),6,2));
```

(3) query data from temp table

```
SELECT gl_year, 
       gl_period, 
       0, 
       fd_changed_hr_id, 
       fd_changed_date, 
       fd_admin_fee_rate 
  FROM #temp1;
```

In your case, what it looks like you would want to do is just create a datawindow object with a String retrieval argument (as_szPool) that combines (1) and (2) together and returns effectively the results of (3).  So the query driving your datawindow would look like this:

```
SELECT convert(int,substring(convert(varchar(25), comb),1,4)) gl_year, 
       convert(int,substring(convert(varchar(25), comb),6,2)) gl_period,
       0,
       fd_changed_hr_id, 
       fd_changed_date, 
       fd_admin_fee_rate 
  FROM (SELECT max(convert(decimal(8,2), convert(decimal(8,2),gl_year) + convert(decimal(8,2),gl_period) / 100)) comb,
               fd_changed_hr_id, 
               fd_changed_date, 
               fd_admin_fee_rate 
          FROM fd_pool_af_history 
         WHERE fd_pool = :as_szPool
         GROUP BY fd_changed_hr_id, 
                  fd_changed_date, 
                  fd_admin_fee_rate
       ) data
```

Then your `dw_select.Retrieve(szPool)` call would return the data you are seeking.

Also here are some details on the [datawindow.table.select property](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc00045_0250/html/ddref/CAIDIABE.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation. I just had a workaround by passing set nocount on and it was retrieving results in the application. But will try your solution too.